# ValueError: Invalid frequency when resampling

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex, resample

I want to resample a temporal series index with pandas resample. In my case I divide to total period by the amount of intervals to get the step. Then sometimes I get the error:

```
ValueError: Invalid frequency: 65.117651L
```

Below I show the index and the error.
You can reproduce the error:

```
pd.DataFrame(index=index).resample('65.117651L')
...
ValueError: Invalid frequency: 65.117651L
```

Should I modify the frequency a bit the ValueError disapears.

Any idea?

The index is:

```
index = DatetimeIndex(['2023-09-14 10:41:11.816999936',
               '2023-09-14 10:41:12.002000128',
               '2023-09-14 10:41:12.101999872',
               '2023-09-14 10:41:12.112999936',
               '2023-09-14 10:41:12.210000128',
               '2023-09-14 10:41:12.308999936',
               '2023-09-14 10:41:12.311000064',
               '2023-09-14 10:41:12.408999936',
                  '2023-09-14 10:41:12.424000',
               '2023-09-14 10:41:12.523000064',
                  '2023-09-14 10:41:12.828000',
               '2023-09-14 10:41:12.829999872',
                  '2023-09-14 10:41:12.924000'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='TS', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already using nanoseconds, so you can use `N` modifier:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index).resample("65117651N")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
DatetimeIndexResampler [freq=<65117651 * Nanos>, axis=0, closed=left, label=left, convention=start, origin=start_day]
```